# Https FileNotFound

Tags: httpsurlconnection, android, java

Привет всем! Пытаюсь получить данные с сервера, но по какой-то причине вылетает FileNotFoundException: https://api.iiko.net:9900/api/0/auth/access_token

Соединяемся с сервером:

```
 String result = new String();

                trustAllHosts();

                URL url = new URL("https://api.iiko.net:9900/api/0/auth/access_token");

                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);

                // set Timeout and method
                conn.setReadTimeout(7000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                conn.connect();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                String inputLine;

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    result += inputLine;
                }
```

Код функции trustAllHosts и DO_NOT_VERIFY:

```
 // always verify the host - dont check for certificate
final static HostnameVerifier DO_NOT_VERIFY = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
};

private static void trustAllHosts()
{
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager()
    {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
        {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       String authType) throws CertificateException
        {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       String authType) throws CertificateException
        {
        }
    } };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    try
    {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection
                .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Если попробовать через браузер то все находиться....